# How to make a form not redirect immediatly if a certain string is detected, but only after submiting?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a form to put in my website and I wanted it to redirect to a URL if a certain string was submitted in that form. But now it redirects immediatly if the string is detected in the form and I only want it to redirect if that string is submitted... How can I solve this problem? Here is the code I've made:

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">
  <textarea name="inputBox123" id="myTextarea" oninput="myFunction(this)">
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submeter"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(val) {
    var testThis = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    if ( testThis.indexOf("launch") > -1 ) {
      window.location = 'http://www.cateto.weebly.com/benoit.html';
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't use the good event to test the string. [`onInput`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) will execute everytime the user writes something in the input. You should use the event [`onSubmit`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) on the form to call your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change input type from "submit" to "button" and add onclick="myFunction()", also add button Label

```html
<form method="POST" id="myform">
<textarea name="inputBox123" id="myTextarea" oninput="myFunction(this)">
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submeter" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(val) {

var testThis = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

if ( testThis.indexOf("launch") > -1 ) {
window.location = 'http://www.cateto.weebly.com/benoit.html';
return false;


}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried again and it worked! Thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Your tag mentions jQuery, so here's an answer that uses it's selectors.

[`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Will stop the default event from triggering, in the circumstance where you might be beholden to using `submit`.

**Example**:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //do other things...
    return  false;
});
```

Here is the [native javascript documentation for event.preventDefault().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)